# how to have flexible height with fixed width

Tags: javascript, css

1. The page has flexible width from 980px to 1200px
2. Has 3 columns
3. Left column is fixed width
4. Middle Column is flexible and large ( so all the extra width will go into this column)
5. Right column is fixed width

### Problem

- Middle Column store a huge articles, however when left and right column is fixed width, it set the height of the whole page.
- Thus it trim the articles
- How to set the middle column as flexible height so that it shows the whole article??**

### Sample Code

```
<div class="col_2">
</div>
<div class="col_1">
</div>
<div class="col_3">

.col_1{padding-left:230px; padding-right:259px;position:absolute; }
.col_2{width:210px; float:left;}
.col_3{width:210px; float:right; margin-right:10px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try ["The Holy Grail"](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail) from A List Apart. Its a three colum fixed left/right liquid centre layout.

Answer (score 0):

For a three-column, left/right fixed, center liquid layout, try:

[CSS Three Column Liquid Layout by Mani Sheriar](http://www.manisheriar.com/holygrail/index.htm)